# Keras flow_from_dataframe wrong data ordering

Tags: python, keras

I am using keras's data generator with flow_from_dataframe. for training it works just fine, but when using model.predict_generator on the test set, I discovered that the ordering of the generated results is different than the ordering of the "id" column in my dataframe.

shuffle=False does make the ordering of the generator consistent, but it is a different ordering than the dataframe. I also tried different batch sizes and the corresponding correct steps for the predict_generator function. (for example: batch_Size=1, steps=len(data))

how can I make sure the labels predicted for my test set are ordered in the same way of my dataframe "id" column?

Comment: Maybe you can find the solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58101761/how-to-enforce-mapping-of-class-indices-in-flow-from-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't found a way to decide the order in which the generator produces data, the order can be obtained with the generator.filenames property.