# How to enforce mapping of class_indices in flow_from_dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, keras, generator

I am setting up a keras data generator using flow_from_dataframe. 
The data are images, and there are 2000 different classes. I have a dataframe which maps the image files to the 2000 categories (integers from 0 to 1999). Both columns (links to images and labels) are formatted as strings.

I have a net that was trained by someone else with a defined mapping from class_indices to labels. Here's the problem: When I set up my data generator with data that I want to test the trained model with, it enforces an alphanumeric ordering on the labels that is different from the one the trained net works with. I now get that "0" is 0, "1" is 1, but "100" is 2, "1000" is 3 etc, but I want that "2" is 2, "3" is 3 etc.

As a consequence, the trained model performs at 0% accuracy.

How can I circumvent the alphanumeric ordering in the data generator (such that "2" is 2, "3" is 3)?

I am using keras 2.2.4. I have tried the following (unsuccesfully):

- transform the column in the pandas dataframe with the labels to %04d-format such that, if alphanumerically sorted, it should result in the desired order -- however, this results in a different order ('0000': 0, '0001': 1, '0007': 2, '0008': 3, '0011' ...)
- provide the "classes" argument to the construction of the data generator with a list in the desired order -- however, this order gets overwritten
- provide the "classes" argument to the construction of the data generator with a dictionary of the desired mapping -- however, again, this gets overwritten and results in the initial problem
  (it seems to work for "flow_from_directory": [Is it possible to change class indices of Keras flow from directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892271/is-it-possible-to-change-class-indices-of-keras-flow-from-directory), but it doesn't work for me with flow_from_dataframe)

What I am trying basically looks like this:

```
    my_generator = my_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=my_df,
        target_size = (224,224),
        directory=None,
        x_col='filename',
        y_col='yID',
        class_mode='categorical',
        classes=classLabels,
        validate_filenames=False,
        batch_size=128)
```

where classLabels can be

```
classLabels = list(map(str,range(2000)))
```

or

```
classLabels = list(map(str,range(2000)))
classLabels = dict(zip(classLabels,list(range(2000))))
```

Expected result is that in `my_generator.class_indices`, I get `{'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, ...}`.
 Actual results are e.g.

- `{'0000': 0, '0001': 1, '0007': 2, '0008': 3, '0011' ...}` when transforming the dataframe column to have 4 digits
- `{'0': 0, '1': 1, '100': 2, '1000': 3, '1002': 4, ...}` when I do or do not provide the "classes" argument [whether as dict or list doesn't matter] when creating the generator

It could very well be that I am overseeing the actual problem (perhaps this is very well possible but I am just missing a detail that I might not even be reporting here -- please excuse me if this is the case, and do not hesitate to think of solutions to my problem that are simpler than I thought).
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kind and clever colleague came to help.

That it gives the weird order when transforming the label column to 4 digit strings was because the specific (testing) dataframe didn't have all 2000 classes, but just a subset.

So in principle, the 4 digit transformation was the right way to go (in case someone needs this: `my_df['yID'] = my_df['yID'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)`).

The only thing that was missing then was additionally specifying a `classLabels` dictionary where the strings are in 4 digit format as well:

```
classLabels = list(map(lambda x: "{:04d}".format(x),range(2000)))
classLabels = dict(zip(classLabels,list(range(2000))))
```

So basically just combining the things I was trying.

Would still be cool if this was possible directly within keras, i.e., if flow_from_dataframe had an option to turn off the alphanumeric sorting.